# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: gradle, duplicates, version

I manually implement 28.0.0 dependency but I found duplicate dependency(28.0.0 and 24.0.0) 
so i want to exclude or remove this(support:24.0.0) dependency from my gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/Shutterbug-1.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score -1):

For me I had to add the following.

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'